# SWT Style Flag - which are applicable for a composite?

Tags: java, swt

after googleing a bit im stuck in finding out which SWT. flags I can use for a composite. The reference here [Ref](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html) does not give me any idea...e.g. the constructor details list `NO_BACKGROUND, NO_FOCUS, NO_MERGE_PAINTS, NO_REDRAW_RESIZE, NO_RADIO_GROUP, EMBEDDED, DOUBLE_BUFFERED` but you can also pass `SWT.BORDER`, and it has an effect. Maybe someone can tell me where to find, or, what keywords I should google. I used "swt composite styles" but...;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that you can use `SWT.BORDER` because `Control` provides it and `Composite` is a subclass of `Control`.

As far as I see you can use the following in addition to those given in the documentation to `Composite`:

- from `Scrollable`:

  - `SWT.H_SCROLL`
  - `SWT.V_SCROLL`
- from `Control`:

  - `SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT`
  - `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`
  - `SWT.BORDER`

Answer (score 3):

More styles are used by the superclasses of Composite.

Here's what I found so far:

- `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control`

  - `SWT.BORDER`
  - `SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT`
  - `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`
- `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable`

  - `SWT.H_SCROLL`
  - `SWT.V_SCROLL`
- `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite`

  - `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND`
  - `SWT.NO_FOCUS`
  - `SWT.NO_MERGE_PAINTS`
  - `SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE`
  - `SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP`
  - `SWT.EMBEDDED`
  - `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED`

These are the styles mentioned in the javadoc for the constructors of the classes. Looking at the source code would show if there are more 'hidden' styles.

Comment: I have accepted the other answer because he has less score. Hope you dont mind.

Comment: Of course, using 'hidden styles' could break the program in future versions. Also sorry for 'stealing' the accepted answer. Your answer was a minute earlier than mine.

Answer (score 0):

A composite can use two kind of style, one is its own, others is inherited from super class.

**Composite**

- SWT.NO_BACKGROUND
- SWT.NO_FOCUS
- SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE
- SWT.NO_MERGE_PAINTS
- SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP
- SWT.EMBEDDED
- SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED
- SWT.UP

And styles from superclass:

**org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable**

- H_SCROLL
- V_SCROLL

**org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control**

- SWT.BORDER,
- SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT

**org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget**

- SWT.NONE

The eclipse wiki has listed the style for composite as well as other widgets, you can refer to this document:https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits